# Securing an Admin Network for IT Administrators

Tags: network, account-security, server, administration

I look forward to your suggestions. We are concerned with the question of how to best and most easily implement a secure admin network for our IT administrators.

Our team consists of three groups - Network, Server, and Support - and each team has specific tasks related to permissions. Each administrator has two AD accounts: a personal one and an administrative one. Currently, all PCs are in the same network, which poses potential security risks as it allows access to other networks.

Our network team requires external support from manufacturers, for example, for the firewall, which needs to be conducted via video conferencing.

We are now looking for ways to introduce a secure environment for all IT teams, allowing each team to fulfill its tasks while keeping the admin network protected. Do you have any suggestions?

A proposal has already been made to access the other components from a central computer, a so-called Admincenter. However, we are aware that this is not an ideal solution. Therefore, we are open to alternative ideas and expert advice.

Thank you in advance for your support!